# Gridview item issue

Tags: android, gridview

Hi everyone I am new in android and so I want your helps.I have a gridview and I want this when for example when I clicked fifth item the second item and fifth item will be pressed how can I do that is it possible?

> **UPDATE:**

Here the code:

```
 public View getView(final int arg0, final View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {

final HashMap<String,ViewFlipper> hashMap=new HashMap<String,ViewFlipper>();
LayoutInflater layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
final ViewHolder viewHolder=new ViewHolder();

if(arg1==null){
view=new View(context);
view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_flipper, null);
viewHolder.text=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.name);
viewHolder.image=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.picture);

viewHolder.image.setImageResource(icons[arg0]);

}else{
    view=(View)arg1;
}
final ViewFlipper  flipper = (ViewFlipper)view.findViewById(R.id.my_view_flipper);

 flipper.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(final View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        AnimationFactory.flipTransition(flipper, FlipDirection.LEFT_RIGHT);
        Animation animation=flipper.getInAnimation();

        animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {


            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                flipper.setEnabled(false);
            }


            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            }


            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                counter++;
            hashMap.put(""+counter, flipper);
                flipper.setEnabled(true);

                Log.i("counter", ""+counter);

                if(counter%2==0){
                    hashMap.get(""+counter).performClick();

                }

            }

        });


    }
});
 return view;
```

}

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more? Plus what have you tried till now?

Comment: as i sai for example when i clicked fifth item the viewflipper in fifth and second item of girdview will be flip

Comment: what do you mean by flip? do you want to exchange the contents of 2nd and fifth item?

Comment: no i pressed fifth and second item will pressed and both of them will displayed an animation

Comment: both item start an animation same time

Comment: but iclicked only fifth

Comment: public your adapter code

Comment: you want only for 5th item or all the items?

Comment: i want same thing for all items

Comment: like for 7th item you want the 4th item to be clicked too?

Comment: give your code I will try it... I can give it a shot...

Comment: i post code look plz